# ASP.NET MVC Pass model from view into controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the need to pass the current model of the view, from the view into a controller, upon a button click.

This is to export the current data to Excel.

What is the best way to do this?  I keep trying to pass the Model from the view into a JS function as such:

```
onclick = "ExportToExcel(this.Model);"
```

But, the data is being passed into the JS as undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to post your model object using and as @Raynos said, get download link.
To do that, you'll to convert your model (cs/vb) to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The Model, after reaching the View from Controller (initially at the page load) is no longer accessible, I mean it sort of does not exist any more as an `Object` you can say. So, you cannot directly pass the model back to JS/Controller. If you want to pass any particular data from Model to JS, you can do so by actually "writing" the data in a hidden input and access this from Java Script using the input id by jQuery.

PS: I know this is pretty old question but I just wanted to know if I'm correct about this. :)

Answer (score 0):

the onclick code will get run in global scope so `this === window`.

I'd assume `window.Model` is `undefined`

Try

```
element.onclick = function() {
  ExportToExcel(this.Model);
};
```

For the record, exporting data to excel should be done on the server and should return a link to an excel file that get's temporary created on the server that users can download

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have tried this, both with quote marks and without, and the function does not now get called.  Also, the excel exporting willbe doneon the server, I just need to get the data to the controller/javascript and then it will be passed onto the Model class on the server to do the logic.

Comment: @DarrenYoung your supposed to use JavaScript to attach the onclick function handler to the element, not add it as an attribute in the HTML

Comment: Thanks, I have it recognising the command now.  But it still won't recognise this.Model.  Sorry for obvious questions, I'm new to MVC asp.net.  Thanks.

Comment: @DarrenYoung I also made the mistake of thinking this would fix your problem. I dont know enough about asp.net mvc off hand to see where the Model lives in the javascript